# JQPlot Dragable constrainTo property doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have a chart plotting by jqplot, it consists of dynamical number of lines based on the DataSeriesToPlot. I want all lines can only be dragged in Y axis, but the constrain to Y property doesn't work. Here is my code, it's highly appreciated if you can help me !!

```
$j.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

        plot1 = $j.jqplot('chart', DataSeriesToPlot,

        {
            animate : true,

            title : 'Draggable Chart Demo',
            neighborThreshold : -1,
            legend : {
                renderer : $j.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,

                show : true,
                labels : legendTypes,
                showSwatch : true,
                predraw : false,
                placement : "outsideGrid",
            },

            seriesDefaults : {

                dragable : {
                    color : '#fffdf6',
                    constrainTo : 'y',

                }

            },

            axes : {

                xaxis : {

                    pad : 1.1,
                    renderer : $j.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,

                    labelRenderer : $j.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    label : 'Month',
                    labelOptions : {
                        labelPosition : 'middle',
                        fontFamily : 'Helvetica',
                        fontSize : '14pt'
                    },
                    tickRenderer : $j.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions : {
                        mark : 'outside',
                        showMark : true,
                        showGridLine : true,
                        show : true,
                        showLabel : true,
                        fontWeight : 'normal',

                        angle : -30,
                        formatString : '%F'

                    },
                    tickInterval : "4 months",

                    showTicks : true,
                    showTickMarks : true

                },
                yaxis : {
                    min : mbMin * 0.8,
                    max : mbMax * 1.2,

                    tickRenderer : $j.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions : {
                        mark : 'outside',
                        showMark : true,
                        showGridLine : true,
                        show : true,
                        showLabel : true,
                        fontWeight : 'normal',
                        formatString : '%.2f'

                    },
                    labelRenderer : $j.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,

                    labelOptions : {

                        fontFamily : 'Helvetica',
                        fontSize : '14pt'

                    },
                    label : 'MB Per Sub',
                },

            },
            highlighter : {
                sizeAdjust : 10,
                showTooltip : true,
                fadeTooltip : true,
                tooltipFadeSpeed : "fast",
                tooltipOffset : 2,
                tooltipAxes : 'both',
                tooltipLocation : 'n',
                tooltipSeparator : ', ',
                useAxesFormatters : true
            },

            cursor : {
                show : true,
                showTooltip : true,
                followMouse : true,
                //showTooltipOutsideZoom : true,
                constrainOutsideZoom : false,
                showTooltipGridPosition : false,
                showTooltipUnitPosition : false,
                useAxesFormatters : true,
                zoom : true,
                looseZoom : true

            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Try putting the dragable object in the series option.

```
series: [{
    dragable : {
      color : '#fffdf6',
      constrainTo : 'y',
    }
}]
```

It should work.